# Why the following python code works?

Tags: python, syntax

```
class Square:                          
    def __init__(self,start,stop):     
        self.value = start - 1
        self.stop = stop
    def __iter__(self):
        return  self           
    def next(self):
        if self.value == self.stop:
            raise   StopIteration                                             
        self.value += 1
        return self.value ** 2
for i in Square(1,4):
    print i,
```

Which outputs

> 1 4 9 16

Comment: It "works" in some sense because it's syntactically valid. Any other definition of "works" relies on the subjective property of what it's *supposed* to do. If you're actually asking *How*, then perhaps that's what you should call your question?

Comment: They're called iterators. Generally __iter__() returns a separate iterator object, but this Square class is both the container and the iterator. See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

If that was your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical Python iteration protocol: `for y in x...` is as follows:

```
iter = x.__iter__()         # get iterator
try:
    while 1:
        y = iter.next()         # get each item
        ...                     # process y
except StopIteration: pass  # iterator exhausted
```

from
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/iterators.html

Comment: Eck. it should be `it=iter(x)` . Don't shadow builtins (don't assign to a variable called iter, map, int, etc.), and don't call `__special__` methods directly except in extraordinary circumstances (such as when you are overriding and need to call on the parent). Also, you should probably explain the relation to a for loop more clearly. Oh, looks like you plagiarized the source. Nevermind. Write your own answer.

Comment: @Devin good point! but i think the asker wants the direct answer, so I just attach the direct answer with losing some good style..

Answer (score 1):

why wouldn't it?  It looks like a normal iterator to me...

the `next()` method is a 'known' method in python that along with the `__iter__()` method signals a generator.

[Here is the python docs on iterators.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#iterators)

Comment: It's not a generator, it's an iterator.

Comment: Thanks Devin. I just read them together, and went with the latter.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Python iterator: every time through the loop the next() method is called

Answer (score 1):

It's an iterator.

Normally though, you would write it using yield.

```
def Square(start, stop):
    for value in xrange(start, stop + 1):
        yield value ** 2

for i in Square(1, 4):
    print i,
```